# Schwarz rearrangement for a function with one variable fixed

Tags: lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives, decreasing-rearrangements

Decompose Euclidian space as $\mathbb{R}^N = \mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathbb{R}^{m}$. If $u \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ I know it is well defined the Schwarz rearrangement of $u$ and the Pólya–Szegő inequality is also valid if $u \geq 0$. For each $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ define $v_x(y) = u(x,y)$. I am wondering why is it well defined the Schwarz rearrangement of $v_x$. For me it is not clear that $v_x \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^m)$ (if it was the case, I would know the Schwarz rearrangement would be well defined). I saw this technique in  [this paper](http://www.numdam.org/item/RSMUP_2002__107__139_0/), LEMMA 3.1. (for simpliicty, just take $\alpha = 0$ in the paper).

Any help about this topic is very welcome.